# PHP Frameworks - Is there a "best" one?

Tags: php, frameworks, classification

I know this is an open-ended question, but is there a PHP Framework that's generally acclaimed as being "the best"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes - the one you are most comfortable with.

I know it sounds glib, but it's true. The best framework is the one you can produce the best work in. They all have their advantages. The question is like asking "which is the best screw" - there's no answer to that question without knowing more about where it is going to be used, or what it has to cope with, or what screwdrivers are available ...

Comment: Let's say it's a fresh start. :)

Comment: That's true, but for example jQuery is considered to be "the best" JavaScript framework at the moment, simply by the majority of people using it vs. users of other frameworks. I guess that's what I was asking. Thanks though.

Comment: I suspect the developers of mootools and the other frameworks would disagree, as would anyone happier in those frameworks than jQuery :)

Comment: Obviously, but numbers are not negociable is what I meant.

Comment: I agree. But numbers are also not a measure of quality. They are a measure of popularity. If you measure quality by numbers, you'd have to agree that IE is the best browser on the market, Gillette make the best razors in the world and the Toyota Corolla is the best car of all time.

Comment: All of those 3 statements are true though. :) In anycase, you are right, hence the quotes around `the best`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Each of them are usually the best one for people who use it ;)

So, i'd like to say that the best one is the one you know the best, the one that make you work faster.